Output File Format limited to JPEG and PNG
I'm trying to export in EXR Multilayer but my Blender only lets me export PNG or JPEG.  I tried every other output file format, but once selected it simply appears as JPEG or PNG.
Has this happened to anyone?



you changed the output folder to exr. But you have to change the file format to exr.

Yes, that's the thing, it doesn't allow me to change the file format to exr.  Once I select the OpenExr file format, it acts as if I selected JPEG.  No matter what file format I choose, they all end up as JPEG, except PNG as PNG.

what do you mean by "it acts like"....does it show "openexr" in file format or not? because in your provided image you have chosen jpeg, not openexr

I meant that even if I click OpenEXR, the file format said JPEG ( in the first photo, OpenEXR has the mouse on top, that's why it's gray, but later the output file selected is JPEG).  However, I uninstalled a couple of addons I had and now it seems to be working.  Thank you Chris.  Have to be careful with addons in the future.
